# Отображение схемы базы данных в приложении WPF

Tags: sql, wpf, entity-framework

создаю приложение WPF, построил с помощью ADO model, диаграмму из SQL server и начал задумываться над вопросом, как визуализировать схему базы данных для администратора. Не нашел про это информацию, поэтому решил задать вопрос - Как это сделать?